# Can an app in development affect other apps on the phone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am having this weird issue while developing an app on iOS 10. Since I started testing it on my iPhone, other apps I have such as Facebook, Slack, LINE or Google Photos get randomly signed out quite often, like multiple times a day.

Could this be related to my app at all? It uses `UserDefaults` and Keychain to handle user log in/out within my app. I have a feeling that those two *might* have something to do with this but I'm not so sure.

I read that this was an issue when iOS 7 first came out but I found nothing regarding iOS 10. So I think it's just me.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's some obscure bug in iOS 10, there is nothing you can do in your iOS app that can affect any other app. That's the whole point of sandboxing. One app can't mess with another.

This assumes your iOS device is not jailbroken and you are only using public APIs in your app. If you are using private APIs or developing on a jailbroken device, then anything is possible.

Comment: My iPhone is not jailbroken. And the app makes network requests using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to our private RESTful API. You think that could be the cause?

Comment: no, by private APIs he means undocumented APIs written by Apple and used by the device. Accessing these is possible and can have unintended consequences, but you would know if you were doing that. Alamofire would not be a problem. Does everything go back to normal when you take the app off?

Comment: @BJHStudios (1) Hm that could happen. I'm using the KeychainWrapper Apple provided in their [Keychain Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1). And yeah I deleted the app and now everything is normal again.